SIGFPE while importing numpy into Python3
I ran into a very odd issue. If I have the following C and Python codes:
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_Initialize();
  FILE* to_run_script= fopen("script.py", "r");
  if (to_run_script != NULL)
    PyRun_SimpleFile(to_run_script, "script.py");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}

and
def func1():
    print("numpy NOT YET imported!!\n")
    import numpy
    print("numpy is imported!!\n")
    return 1.5

func1()

Then everything works as expected, Python starts and I get both output lines.
However, when I embed the same piece of code in our code (which does some setup, but I'm not exactly sure what) then the import numpy statement throws a SIGFPE (more precisely, FPE_FLTOVF, at least that's what strace says) and the code exits without printing the second line.
To further muddy the waters, if I run through valgrind the very same code that produced SIGFPE, then everything works again.
At this point I'm baffled and would be glad for any suggestions for what I should check.

This? https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20504

Yes, I have found that (and a couple of more detailed ones, like https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/18202). It is likely related. The difference is that for me the plain (non-embedded) C code works fine, I get no SIGFPE, while when I embed the same C code I do get SIGFPE. Also, why there is a SIGFPE when I run the embedded code, but no SIGFPE when I run the same code through valgrind (and no errors reported by valgrind, either)?

Please post also makefile (or just gcc/clang command line) that works with your snippet but causes a crash of the "embedded" version. File names can differ, but the same flags should be applied in both cases.

The code was compiled with:
"export PYTHON=$HOME/Python3.11.3; gcc -o example_python -I${PYTHON}/include/python3.11 example_python.c -L${PYTHON}/lib -lpython3.11"
numpy was installed in a virtual env using that python, so I ran it as:
"export PYTHONEXECUTABLE=$HOME/python3.11.3_venv/bin/python; ./example_python"

The embedded version... That is a mess :-(. But it uses the same include files, same python related libs, and at runtime it has the same PYTHONEXECUTABLE (so that the pip-installed numpy can be found) setting.

And the most baffling to me is that the very same code that gets a sigfpe runs fine under valgrind. Usually it's the other way around...
